# How can I formulate this sentences correctly?

Tags: syntax

How can I formulate this sentences correct?

**Singular**

> - We do have an employee which is call John Doe.
> - We do have an employee which is called John Doe.

**Plural**

> - We do have employees, which are call John Doe, Tony Doe, Jane Doe.
> - We do have employees, which are called John Doe, Tony Doe, Jane Doe.

**What do I want to say is, **

> - Singular:  ... that we do have a employee which has the name John Doe.
> - Plural: ... that we do have employees, which has the name John Doe, Tony Doe, Jane Doe.

Comment: You should use "who".

Comment: OK thanks for the hint. Does it make any difference between `call` and `called`?

Comment: It is passive (BE+past participle). So it should be "called".

Comment: You should probably [edit] your post to include why you think the first option could have been possible, because I've never encountered it like that.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand which part pf the sentence mean? Im not sure too, thats why i am asking here. If the correct way is completle different, than I am happy to hear, how to build the sentence.